# Cant draw Shapes in Java

Tags: java, swing

another java swing question. I really really searched for lots of hours but i cant get my code working.. so i hope you guys can help me out. I think i have some fundamental understanding issues.

I have to expand existing code.
My first task was to draw a line from mouseclick to release, i implemented that successfully.

Now I should implement missing code in the RandomDrawer class to draw circles with the click of the JMenuItem. They should be random and all, but that is not important right now, i can do this WHEN i actually draw oder SEE my shapes :D.

My problem is i can't get it to draw anything at all.
How can i tell him to paint on the canvas? 
It worked in the Painter Class, when i implement it in the same way to the RandomDrawer Class it does not.
Can someone help me?

Here is my code so far:

```
    package plotterpackage;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Point;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
    import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
    import java.awt.geom.Line2D;

    import javax.swing.JComponent;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JMenu;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
    import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

    /

public class Main {
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel canvas;
    private JPanel statusBar;
    private JTextField status;

    public Main() {
        initialize();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main app = new Main();
        app.start();
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame("Main");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setBounds(50,50, 50+640, 50+480);
        frame.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        frame.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());

        frame.getContentPane().add(createContent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(createStatusBar(),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    public void start() {
        // show the GUI
        frame.setVisible(true);
        status.setText("Application started");
    }

    protected JComponent createContent() {
        canvas = new JPanel();
        canvas.addMouseListener(new Painter());
        canvas.setBackground(new Color(128,218,255));
        canvas.setForeground(Color.RED);
        canvas.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED));
        return canvas;
    }

    protected JComponent createStatusBar() {
        FlowLayout layout = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
        layout.setHgap(5);

        statusBar = new JPanel(layout);
        statusBar.add(new JLabel("Status: "));

        status = new JTextField();
        status.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,25));
        status.setEditable(false);
        status.setBorder(new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED,Color.MAGENTA,Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
        status.getInsets().set(2, 10, 2, 10);
        statusBar.add(status);

        return statusBar;
    }

    protected JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenuItem item;
        JMenu menu;
        // Action menu
        menu = new JMenu("Actions");
        mb.add(menu);
        item = new JMenuItem("Draw RandomCircle");
        item.addActionListener(new RandomDrawer());
        menu.add(item);

        item = new JMenuItem("Draw RandomTriangle");
        item.addActionListener(new RandomDrawer());
        menu.add(item);

        menu.addSeparator();
        item = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        item.addActionListener(new AppCloser());
        menu.add(item);

        // Color menu not used so far
        menu = new JMenu("Colors");        
        mb.add(menu);
        // Help menu not used so far
        menu = new JMenu("Help");        
        mb.add(menu);

        return mb;
    }

    class AppCloser implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.printf("application finished, bye-bye... \n");
            frame.setVisible(false);
            frame.dispose();
            System.exit(0);
        }        
    }

    class RandomDrawer extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        @Override 
        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawOval(50, 50, 50, 50);
            //repaint();
        }
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            double x = Math.random();
            double y = Math.random();
            status.setText(String.format("rnd draw x:%.3f y:%.3f",x,y));
            //Graphics2D gg = (Graphics2D) canvas.getGraphics();
            //paintComponent(gg);
            //gg.draw(new Line2D.Double(0, 0, x, y));
            //gg.drawLine(5, 5, 20, 20);
            //gg.paintComponent();
        }


    }


    class Painter extends MouseAdapter {
        Point start, end;
        int startX, startY;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            start = e.getPoint();
            startX = e.getX();
            startY = e.getY();
            status.setText(String.format("Mouse start: " + start));

        }


        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            end = e.getPoint();
            status.setText(String.format("Mouse end: " + end));
            Graphics2D gc = (Graphics2D) canvas.getGraphics();
            //gc.drawLine(0, 0, 80, 80);
            gc.drawLine(startX, startY, e.getX(), e.getY());
            //gc.drawOval(startX, startY, e.getX(), e.getY());
            //gc.fillOval(startX, startY, e.getX(), e.getY());
        }        
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: A big help for me is to track whatever your code is doing by adding *a lot* of prints to each method (and inside those methods, before or after each atomic call). Then you can track the execution of your code and find whatever is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to also include MouseMotionListener, to your canvas.

```
 Painter painter = new Painter();
canvas.addMouseListener(painter);
canvas.addMouseMotionListener(painter);
```

Also to add draw effect to your rectangle you need to change you Painter class as follows :
Replace your Painter class with this and run application, you can draw rectangle as per paint application. Learn what I changed in class and let me know if any questions :

```
class Painter extends MouseAdapter implements MouseMotionListener
  {
    Point start, end;

    Point oldStart, oldEnd;

    int startX, startY, oldX, oldY, oldWidth, oldHeight;

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
      start = e.getPoint();
      oldX = startX;
      oldY = startY;
      startX = e.getX();
      startY = e.getY();
      status.setText(String.format("Mouse start: " + start));

    }

    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
      Graphics2D gc = (Graphics2D)canvas.getGraphics();
      end = e.getPoint();
      gc.setColor(new Color(128, 218, 255));
      gc.drawOval(oldX, oldY, oldWidth, oldHeight);
      oldX = startX;
      oldY = startY;
      oldWidth = e.getX();
      oldHeight = e.getY();
      gc.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      gc.drawOval(startX, startY, e.getX(), e.getY());
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
    {
      end = e.getPoint();
      status.setText(String.format("Mouse end: " + end));
      Graphics2D gc = (Graphics2D)canvas.getGraphics();
      oldX = 0;
      oldY = 0;
      oldWidth = 0;
      oldHeight = 0;

    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks a lot Sandeep.K, i fully understood what your code does and it helped me alot understanding the concept! and it does work

Comment: I did, sorry.. new :)